# iTunnesConnect version management

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, versioning

Is it possible to deploy an app with lower version to iTunnesConnect (testflight)?

Let's consider this example:

- last uploaded version was 2.0.0 (currently in production)
- started a new feature to be released in 2.1.0
- uploaded version to test (2.1.0.featureA001)
- did some work and uploaded another version (2.1.0.featureA002)
- meanwhile, a bug needs to be fixed in prod (currently 2.0.0)
- after the bug fix, it needs to be tested, so the version would be (2.0.1.bugfix001)
- however, 2.0.1.bugfix001 is lower than the last uploaded one, 2.1.0.featureA002
- but it would be necessary to test both at the same time

Accordingly to Apple docs, a version being uploaded needs always to be higher than the previous one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upload builds for any version, even older versions, and make those builds available under TestFlight.

Where you may have a problem with your scenario is that you can only have two versions associated with the App Store; the current release and the next release.

As long as you hadn't created a new app store version for 2.1.0 you could create 2.0.1, upload a build and submit it for approval while still continuing to upload and test 2.1.0 builds under TestFlight.

If you have already created the placeholder for 2.1.0 on the App Store then you cannot create 2.0.1

Within a given version, the build number must be higher than the last build for that version.

Comment: Thanks, got it.. the purpose here is to be able to test in TestFlight. App store shouldn't have  those many versions. Now, if we can upload as many versions to TestFlight only, as long as the version+build is higher, it would be fine.